# Website(web page) time traker

Tags: c#, .net, windows, html

Is there any way out to get the time spent on webpage using c# code.
Or any open source project in .net using which we track the time spent.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with Javascript. You would post back to the server when the browser navigates to another page, and/or at regular intervals with an AJAX call.